# Display Errors Local / Master Value

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

i'm about to set up my first own VPS for my website. cPanel is installed, PHP and MySQL are up to date.

I get some "Strict Errors" on my website, the errors are not a bad thing, but it looks not so nice of course. In my php.ini display_errors is set to off, of course. Because i use cPanel, i can upload a php.ini in the root folder of my user account. This works and should be the local value. But the errors still persist. Now, i got myself a php file with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and uploaded it to the root of my user folder. Looks like [this](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2zp6o7l.jpg). You can see, display_errors local and master value are off. Now, when i go to my Joomla System Information and look into the php information, i see [this](http://oi60.tinypic.com/jztjps.jpg). Here is the local value on. But why?! There is nothing in the .htaccess and when i write something in there like `php_flag display_errors off` it breaks my page with 500 Internal Server Error. Of course, i cleared the cache of Joomla and i tried to find another string with "display_errors", but no luck so far.

Comment: http://www.celticwebdesign.net/joomla-cms/joomla-how-to-turn-off-display-errors/

Comment: Oh man, there is an error reporting in the global configuration ... i knew it would be something super easy - stupid me, haha. Thank you very much :)